# How do I move two parallel arrays from one method to another, by returning to the main method then entering the second one?

Tags: java, arrays

I need both the String and double arrays to go from inputAccept to table:

```
    inputAccept();

    table(names, costs);

    public static void inputAccept() {
           Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
           String[] names = {"","","","","","","","","",""};
           double[] costs = new double[10];

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter the name of item " + (i + 1) + ": ");
                names[i] = scan.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Enter item cost: ");
                costs[i] = scan.nextDouble();
            }
     }

    public static void table(String[] names, double[] costs) {
    //insert code using the arrays
    }
```

I know this is wrong, but I don't know what to do to fix it.

Comment: By not creating parallel arrays, but using the Object-Oriented features a Java and create a *single* array with objects of two fields, i.e. by doing it the right way.

Comment: @GDaniels instead of nextLIne you should use scan.next()

Answer (score 1):

You can just create the two arrays in the main method, then first pass them into the inputAccept method, then pass the two arrays into the table method:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] costs = new double[10];
        String[] names = {"","","","","","","","","",""};
        inputAccept(names, costs);
        table(names, costs);
    }

    public static void inputAccept(String[] names, double[] costs) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the name of item " + (i + 1) + ": ");
            names[i] = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter item cost: ");
            costs[i] = scan.nextDouble();
        }
    }

    public static void table(String[] names, double[] costs) {
    //insert code using the arrays
    }
```

Comment: I have a main method. I was only posting the two relevant methods.

Comment: Copying the code of the question without the first two lines that was trying the represent the main method is hardly an answer to the question.

Comment: I have edited the answer to include a better solution now. I misunderstood the question before.

Comment: Changed down-vote to up-vote. That is an excellent solution that keeps the parallel arrays, don't need static fields, don't need extra classes, and don't need casts.

Answer (score 1):

First it looks like you are creating "items" from user input. I think modeling a *class* `Item` should be a first step:

```
public final class Item {
    private final String name;
    private final double cost;

    public Item(String name, double cost) {
        this.name = name;
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public double getCost() {
        return cost;
    }
}
```

Then `inputAccept()` becomes:

```
public static Item[] inputAccept() {
    Item[] items = new Item[10];

    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter the name of item " + (i + 1) + ": ");
            String name = scan.next();
            System.out.println("Enter item cost: ");
            double cost = scan.nextDouble();

            items[i] = new Item(name, cost);
        }
    }

    return items;
}
```

Therefore, `table(...)` becomes

```
public static void table(Item[] items) {
    // insert code using the arrays
}
```

And the final usage is

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    table(inputAccept());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach is as clean as a baby's bottom

```
private class InputResult {
    //generate constructor with both fields
    String[] names; //generate getter
    double[] costs; //generate getter
}
```

then

```
public static InputResult inputAccept()
    ...
    return new InputResult(names, costs);

public static void table(InputResult input)
    String[] names = input.GetNames();
    ...
```

Comment: Compile error. `obj[0]` not compatible with parameter `String[]`. `obj[1]` not compatible with `double[]`. And don't say cast them, because it's a bad code pattern to bypass the compiler type-checking. Create a class.

Comment: I did think. Did you think to read my comment before commenting? But I guess I missed this: Compiler error. `object` is not a class.

Comment: @Andreas Created a cleaner solution with a class as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {

    static String[] names = {"","","","","","","","","",""};
    static double[] costs = new double[10];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        inputAccept();

        table(names, costs);
    }



    public static void inputAccept() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the name of item " + (i + 1) + ": ");
            names[i] = scan.next();
            System.out.println("Enter item cost: ");
            costs[i] = scan.nextDouble();
        }
    }

    public static void table(String[] names, double[] costs) {
        for (String name: names) {
            System.out.println(name);
        }
        for (double value: costs) {
            System.out.println(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This should solve your problem but I hope this is just for practice. lol

Comment: Why allocate one array in initializer and the other is method? Consistency as a good thing in code.

Comment: This is just to answer OP's question. Further re-factoring can be done later on..